# Android Samsung Galaxy s5 on linux

Tags: android, linux

I am trying to develop android apps from Linux but I can't seem to find drivers for my galaxy s5 for Linux.

Is there a work around or has anybody managed to get those drivers?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need drivers on Linux. At most, you might need to add some settings to a configuration file. Usually, you don't even need that -- just enable USB debugging on the device, plug it in, and go.

Answer (score 3):

Check this Post http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

You need to create file at `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
with below content

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```